# Trying to boil down median sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, median

So you can find the description of this algorithm here:
[Algorithms in a Nutshell](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/algorithms-in-a/9780596516246/ch04s03.html)

So then I think this works as follows:

1. Find the median item rounded down (using floor) & swap it to the middle. How to find it is unspecified.
2. Swap all items greater than median on the left side with items less than the median on the right side.
3. Rescurse down the left side.
4. Recurse down the right side.

Anything I missed? Much about this seems ambiguous. Like how to find the median item.

Comment: does that look like quick sort to anyone?

Comment: I think I smell a rat here. In the case where the right side is larger than the left side, one value may never get checked... so wouldn't you have to start with the larger of the two sub-arrays as the base, i.e. swap from the larger to the other smaller and never the other way around?

Comment: no, because by definition the median splits your array in 2 equal arrays

Comment: finding the median (or pivot) is the big problem of quicksort. your book says so : `Implementing Median Sort depends on efficiently selecting the median element from an unsorted array.`

Comment: but in any quicksort, you may not use the median (the most basic implementation uses the first element of the array). 2 sub-arrays are then created from the first array, one containing the small elements, one containing the large ones. The size of both arrays does not really matter.

Comment: Well, in the case where you have an even number of values ( say 8 ), you have to have 3 on one side and 4 on the other such that if you check the 3, on the left side and ALL of the values on the right are smaller than median, isn't there is one value that never gets checked?

Comment: OIC, as you said, your find widget has to get the right value AND put it in the right place.

Comment: The sort is efficient since finding the median item takes linear time - if, as njzk2 says, done efficiently.  Fortunately, it's not ambiguous, since the book describes - with code - how to perform it (the "selectKth" function), with the added side-benefit that finding the item also does the preparatory swapping !

Comment: @racraman: `with the added side-benefit that finding the item also does the preparatory swapping` - can you expand on that?

Comment: < sarcasm > Yup. It's code therefore there's never anything that seems ambiguous about it. ;-) For humans reading code, it's just like that. < /sarcasm >

Comment: @ 500 - Internal Server Error : Just that from the 4 steps above, if we had some separate loop to find the median in step 1, we'd expect to still have to do step 2.  However, the recursive "selectKth" they've used does the swapping as part of finding the median, so step 2 is done as part of step 1 - neat!

Comment: @user447607 - Sorry - didn't mean to come across as smart-***ed.  To see what's happening, there's a good visualisation (of quicksort) at http://bost.ocks.org/mike/algorithms/#sorting

Comment: @user447607 typically, in the link posted by racraman, the pivot is the middle item (no com
putation of median term) : `var pivot = left + right >> 1;`

Comment: @racraman S'ok.  Thx for visualization.

Comment: in this case they start by taking the median of the first and last values of the array